# Generic List type from JSON Path result

Tags: java, generics, jsonpath

I want to serialize some JSON using a POJO, based on a Generic class passed as a parameter.

The Generic class should extend an abstract class, so that I can call some common methods on the resulting data structure.

I've got this so far:

```
private <T extends TypeInterface> List<DBObject> getDataUsingJsonPath(String path, Class<T> type) {

    TypeRef<List<T>> typeRef = new TypeRef<List<T>>() {};

    Configuration configuration = Configuration
        .builder()
        .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
        .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
        .build();

    List<T> items = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read(path, typeRef);

    result = items.getAggregations();
```

The error:

> Can not construct instance of TypeInterface, problem: abstract types
>   either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer,
>   or be instantiated with additional type information

I'm trying to tell it that  extends TypeInterface, but that the actual Class of  is 'type'... what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

For a rapid solution:

```
private <T extends TypeInterface> List<DBObject> getDataUsingJsonPath(String path, Class<T> type) {

    Configuration configuration = Configuration
        .builder()
        .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
        .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
        .build();

List<T> items = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(jsonString).read(path, (Class<List<T>>) new ArrayList<T>().getClass());
```

The idea is to get rid of `TypeRef<List<T>>` It's working, but produces an warning.

Comment: Nice answer, unfortunately I couldn't iterate over the result as for(T t : items), got a cast exception: LinkedHashMap cannot be cast TypeInterface. See my answer for what I did instead.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will compile `new TypeRef<List<T>>() {};` as a reference to `List<T extends TypeInterface>`, not the element type provided by `type`.

It doesnt look like JsonPath supports further refining a typeref by specifying classes. Looking at the source-code it is possible use a more expanded library like guava with the following modifications:

1. Construct a guava `TypeToken<T>` just like you would a `TypeRef<T>`, but use the `.where(new TypeParameter<T>() {}, type)` to refine the type variable to the final type.
2. Create a wrapper around the new typetoken which provides the refined type to JsonPath:

Wrapper:

```
class TokenRef<T> extends TypeRef<T> {
    private final TypeToken<T> token;

    public TokenRef(TypeToken<T> token) {
        super();
        this.token = token;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return this.token.getType();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good explanation for what is happening, makes sense. I've instead moved the TypeRef<List<T>> to be a parameter of the function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers here but, after some sleep, I've opted  instead to move the TypeRef to be the actual parameter.

```
private <T extends TypeInterface> List<DBObject> getDataUsingJsonPath(String path, TypeRef<List<T>> type) {
```

I can then iterate over the result as expected:

```
List<T> items = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(responseString).read(path, type);

for(T item : items) {
// do generic TypeInterface stuff here
```

I don't know if this is the best, of most correct, 'Generic' way of doing this, but so far so good, and it basically makes sense when reading the code I think.